# Fixed button on scroll

Tags: javascript, css, sass

Managed to add a fixed button when I scroll down the page, but I want to have this hidden until a certain point (when the nav is out of view).

I will show you my code so far and you guys can hopefully show me where I have gone wrong.

**CSS**

```
.fixed-btn {
    position: fixed;
    top: 60px;
    right: 80px;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 999;
    display: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="fixed-btn">
    <a onclick="fatsomaEventsWidget.showEvent('akvmo30l')" href="#event_id=akvmo30l" class="btn btn--white-bg" href="#" role="button">Get Wristbands</a>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var wristbands = $(".fixed-btn");

wristbands.on("scroll", function (e) {

    if (this.scrollTop > 900) {
        wristbands.css('display: block;');
    } else {
        wristbands.css('display: none;');
    }

});
```

Comment: What is the current behaviour of your code ?

Comment: Javascript is unfunctional, so when I remove the display attribute from css it works as intended. All I need help with is hiding the button before a certain scroll point in the page.

Answer (score 1):

I adapted the solution from @Ivan Gajic a bit.. to a more up to date way of coding, using Jquery's premade show() and hide() options

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(document).scrollTop() > 900){
        $(".fixed-btn").show();
    } else {
        $(".fixed-btn").hide();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
         $(window).scroll(function(){
                   if ($(this).scrollTop() > 900) {
                        $(".fixed-btn").fadeIn();
                    } else {
                        $(".fixed-btn").fadeOut();
                    }
           });
```

EDIT:

Remove `display:none` from css

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't scroll $(".fixed-btn"), if it's hidden.
Second, 
    `wristbands.css('display: block;');` is not correct, you have to do  `wristbands.css('display','block');`

Try something like this.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(document).scrollTop() > 900){
        $(".fixed-btn").css("display", "block");
        // do whatever you want
    }
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/qwkv9e6s/4/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).scroll(function () {
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (y > 85) {
            $('.lead-bar').addClass("display");
        } else {
            $('.lead-bar').removeClass("display");
        }
    });
```

```css
.para{margin-top:160px}
.lead-bar{position:absolute;top:0;display:none}
.lead-bar.display{display:block}
.lead-bar.display a{position:fixed;top:15px;right:15px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="lead-bar">
    <a href="#" role="button">Get Wristbands</a>
</div>
<p class="para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

Answer (score -2):

simply add this css to your div or button.. tag

```
style="position: sticky;"
```

enjoy